# Cloud Custodian c7n - Policy to count RDS instances greater than 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudcustodian

Is it possible to write a cloud custodian policy that would tag a RDS database cluster that has an instance count greater than 2?

Can it be done?

I have researched through the AWS c7n documentation and cannot see how this might be done...

Thanks

To count RDS instances greater than 2 in Cloud Custodian...

Comment: You could write a bash script and send the names to c7n to clean up. Might not be the best solution but it should work.